# Difference between declare class in : "__construct" and in the top of file with "use"

Tags: magento2, class, construct

Anyone have idea about declare class in `__construct` and declare class in top of file with `use`.

Exemple:

```
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
```

and

```
public function __construct(
      \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
) {
      $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define the class like below in the top of the page:

```
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
```

then you **__contruct** function will be look like this:

```
public function __construct(
      StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
) {
      $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

and if you not define the class in top then you can also managed it by injecting directly in your **__construct** function like below:

```
public function __construct(
      \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
) {
      $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

Both are same.